# How to hide or edit a message on closure of a ssh ,when ssh was handled using interact in expect script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, expect

I have an expect script which makes user able to login and print some specific info before login,but when I am coming out it it prints "Connection to machine closed." ,I want to change the message which is getting displayed.Script kept it in interact mode.Please help me in finding a solution.

Comment: You can't change this message since it is general message coming from binary, unless you would recompile `ssh`. But anyway, this message is sent to `stderr` and you can redirect it to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick check of the [ssh manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/slogin.1?query=ssh&sec=1) reveals that ssh has a **-q** option:

> **-q**    Quiet mode.  Causes most warning and diagnostic messages to be suppressed.

You can probably read the ssh manual on your own system by running `man ssh`.

Alternately, you could set the [ssh_config parameter](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config&sec=5) to *quiet*:

> **LogLevel**
>  Gives the verbosity level that is used when logging messages
>   from ssh(1). The possible values are: QUIET, FATAL, ERROR, INFO,
>   VERBOSE, DEBUG, DEBUG1, DEBUG2, and DEBUG3. The default is INFO. DEBUG
>   and DEBUG1 are equivalent. DEBUG2 and DEBUG3 each specify higher
>   levels of verbose output.

Here is the actual code block which emits that message. You can see that it's suppressed when the loglevel is quiet:

```
if (have_pty && options.log_level != SYSLOG_LEVEL_QUIET) {
        snprintf(buf, sizeof buf,
            "Connection to %.64s closed.\r\n", host);
        buffer_append(&stderr_buffer, buf, strlen(buf));
}
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks for providing a solution...I am getting two prints "Connection to machine closed by remote host." and one is  "Connection to machine closed." ,after putting -q or loglevel QUIET ..it is hiding  "Connection to machine closed." but NOT the first one.Please help

Comment: Yes, you're right. The "...by remote host" message is emitted even when the log level is quiet.

Comment: is there any way to hide that too?